# The Witcher 3 Heart of Stone Auction

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone

In the Witcher 3 Addon Heart of Stone you can buy different items in an auction. I remember the

> glasses of the guy who attacke Kaer Morhen and a statue which is said to have a treasure inside of it.

Is there any point in buying any of the items? Will some of them have an outcome?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In that auction, I bought all 3 of them. Simply because I'm damn rich and I wanted to show that to everyone.

- The glasses are simply glasses. You can destroy them for some materials, but as far as I know, there is nothing valuable inside.
- The picture is quite valuable, you can sell it in Novigrad for a good amount of money.
- The statue is worth it, but to be honest, I can't remember what it was inside, I'll check my save file once I'm at home. But I do know that it was definitely worth it, so buy it and let a smith destroy it.

**Edit - Contents of the statue:**

The statue contains a key and a letter which will unlock a new quest after reading it. You will also discover a new location where you will have to travel. Inside are a few enemies (mainly wolves) and a recipe of a steel sword called **[Black Unicorn](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Black+Unicorn)**.

Comment: @Thanathan Since i got my Laptop here, i could check the inventory and remembered the contents of the statue. I've edited it into the answer.

Comment: Uhh that sounds nice. Seems like I need to replay the Addon and get buy that statue :D Thanks for checking!

Comment: I did not participate in the auction because I had just pumped 30.000 crowns into the runewright... :(

Comment: @Exa Since everything is placed on start and not added dynamically through quests, you can still obtain the black unicorn recipe. You just have to find the place :p

Comment: You can equip the glasses in your pocket and Geralt will wear them 

Answer (score 1):

The painting is an allusion to Van Gogh's "Starry Night over the Rhone", in the game called " Starry Night Over the Pontar" by Van Rogh. And the glasses allude to the glasses worn by the main character (an assassin) in the movie "The Professional". In the game, they say they belonged to an assassin called the Professor. I think they were just thrown into the game for fun.

Comment: Actually in the books there is an assassin called Proffesor and Geralt kills him because he is searching for Ciri.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the painting goes, if you identify the correct artist's work in the chat with the art dealer beforehand he'll suggest you buy it and tell you the bookseller in Novigrad will pay top coin for it. Vimi will ask you what he said, but don't share the info or he'll bid against you and you'll end up paying 3 times the price.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the glasses are a reference to the second book 'The Time of Contempt' There is an assassin hired to kill Geralt called the professor who wears those glasses.

Comment: Hi, I think that this is asking more about what the point of the glasses are for rather than the lore behind them. Please feel free to visit the (Help Center)[https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help] for more help and information for future answers. Have a nice day.